# IQ test question (double-arrow with inverted flukes)

Tags: geometry

I found the following question in the [New Zealand Mensa practice test](http://nzlweb.com/index.php):

[image]

According to the website, **the solution is B**:

> The first symbol is a double-arrow with inverted flukes. The second is
> the same but with normal flukes and rotated counter-clockwise 135
> degrees. The correct answer must follow the 135 degree rotation and
> have inverted flukes. B is correct.

So if I rotate the 1st symbol counter-clockwise by 135 degrees and invert the flukes I get the 2nd symbol:

[image]

However, if I follow the same procedure with B, I get this:

[image]

[This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h36cpwlslHk) implies the rotation has to be done clockwise:

[image]

I was wondering if there was a better explanation for this puzzle, because arbitrarily changing the direction of the rotation doesn't seem fair to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this better, I followed the link to the test and looked at the group of questions (23-26). What I noticed was:

> Although the question appears to imply that you would take your answer and convert it into the last shape, what I see with the other 3 questions is that they take the last shape and convert it into the answer shape. For example:
>  Question 23 column 1 has a shape with 3 circles, column 2 has a shape with 2 circles. Column 4 has a shape with 3 squares, and the correct answer (D) has a shape with 2 squares.
>  Question 24 column 1 has a filled in shape, column 2 has an outline shape that the shape in column 1 fits into. Column 4 has a filled in shape, and the correct answer (C) has an outline shape that the shape in column 4 fits into.

So, for the question at hand,

> Column 4 has a shape, that if rotated 135 degrees counter-clockwise and has the flukes inverted, gives answer B.

Comment: Indeed, fair enough!